# Link direcionando para home, ao invés de chamar ação do js

Tags: javascript, html

`<a href="#!" class="dashboard-nav-item dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle"> Ferramentas </a>` ao invés de abrir a aba, ele joga para a página inicial.
O Javascript dele é:

````
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".dashboard-nav-dropdown")
            .toggleClass("show")
            .find(".dashboard-nav-dropdown")
            .removeClass("show");
        $(this).parent()
            .siblings()
            .removeClass("show");
    });
    $(".menu-toggle").click(function () {
        if (mobileScreen.matches) {
            $(".dashboard-nav").toggleClass("mobile-show");
        } else {
            $(".dashboard").toggleClass("dashboard-compact");
        }
    });
});```
````

Comment: O primeiro código foi errado, a chamada é essa: "<a href="#!" class="fechar-painel menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a>"

Answer (score 0):

O funcionamento normal de um link é direcionar para uma página ou posição em uma página caso seja informado um id da página na url precedido de #.

Para prevenir esses funcionamentos, você pode utilizar `preventDefault` no evento click, que impede que o evento continue seu curso normal ou direcionar a `href`para `javascript:void(0);`, que direciona para uma função javascript que não faz nada a não ser descartar o valor zero.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle").click(function (evento) {
        evento.preventDefault(); // impede o funcionamento normal do link
        $('#exemplo').toggle(); // faz qualquer coisa
        
        return; // não vai executar o código abaixo, desnecessário para a explicação
        $(this).closest(".dashboard-nav-dropdown")
            .toggleClass("show")
            .find(".dashboard-nav-dropdown")
            .removeClass("show");
        $(this).parent()
            .siblings()
            .removeClass("show");
    });

    $(".menu-toggle").click(function () {
        if (mobileScreen.matches) {
            $(".dashboard-nav").toggleClass("mobile-show");
        } else {
            $(".dashboard").toggleClass("dashboard-compact");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dashboard-nav-item dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle"> Ferramentas </a>

<div id="exemplo">Ocultar exibir ferramentas</div>
```